# GitHub Action samples link is missing on GitHub repository page of Azure API Management Devops Resource toolkit

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-api-management

There is Azure API Management Devops Resource Toolkit GitHub repository which describes how to deploy Azure API to other API< instance using resource toolkit and provided some links of samples for CICD using different technologies like Azure Devops, GitHub Actions, PowerShell etc.

in that link GitHub link is broken like when we click on it, we get 404 page on GitHub.

Azure API Management Devops resource toolkit link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit

[image]

if anyone has corrected link for GitHub Sample which is broken in this page then, please provide link over here.

Thanks.

Need corrected link for Azure API management GitHub Action CICD pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The Github Actions Link is not available as the Example is only available for Azure Devops.

In order to deploy the APIM with the help of APIM DevOps Resouce Kit Creator tool and Github Actions refer this [**PART 2**](https://blog.memoryleek.co.uk/2021/09/15/deploying-api-management-apis-using-github-actions-part-2.html) Blog by Matthew Fortunka.

Here's his [**Github repository**](https://github.com/fortunkam/apim_api_demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml) that contains the Github Action File for the same and here the [**PART1**](https://blog.memoryleek.co.uk/2021/09/14/deploying-api-management-apis-using-github-actions.html) of the blog where he sets up APIM Policies and config file from APIM DevOps Resource Kit Creator tool.